# PHP multiple preg_replaces

Tags: php

`$motd = "§aTest §bFont";
echo "
<span>
    ". 
    preg_replace('§a', '<font style="color:#55FFFF;">', $motd);
    preg_replace('§b', '<font style="color:#FFAA00;">', $motd)."
</span>";`

**Goal**
Pretty much what I want to do is have "§a" and "§b" act as color codes, and I want them to be replaced as font tags instead of just saying §a or §b. Doing just one preg_replace works, but when I have two preg_replaces it doesn't work.

**Excpected Output**
`<font style="color:#55FFFF;">Test <font style="color:#FFAA00;">Font`
Instead of
`§aTest §bFont`

**This Works**
`$motd = "§aTest §bFont";
echo "
<span>
    ". 
    preg_replace('§a', '<font style="color:#55FFFF;">', $motd)
    ."
</span>";`
But only shows
`<font style="color:#55FFFF;">Test §bFont`
and makes "§bFont" that same color as "§aTest".

Comment: How do you plan to close the `font` tag? Also, `font` is deprecated and you should use `span` instead.

Comment: What will not closing the font tag affect?

Comment: For starters, it's not proper HTML. It will cause everything following it to be colored for the rest of the page.

Comment: I know its not proper HTML its just im not sure where I would add the </font>

Comment: You could theoretically use regex to detect text between §a and §0, and replace them with `<span style="color: #55FFFF;">` and `</span>`.

Comment: Ok thanks for the reply. Now what if there is not another §?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `preg_replace()`

```
$motd = "§aTest §bFont";
$motd = preg_replace('/§a/', '<font style="color:#55FFFF;">', $motd);
$motd = preg_replace('/§b/', '<font style="color:#FFAA00;">', $motd);
```

Using `str_replace()`

```
$motd = "§aTest §bFont";
$motd = str_replace('§a', '<font style="color:#55FFFF;">', $motd);
$motd = str_replace('§b', '<font style="color:#FFAA00;">', $motd);
```

When the replacement is done, do the `echo`

```
echo "
<span>
    $motd
</span>";
```